# CakePHP testing - Import records on the fly

Tags: cakephp, testing, fixtures

I have a lot of tests which used fixed fixtures, which is great for testing things like "am I getting the right number of records back from this method" and similar.

```
class CountryFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $import = array(
        'model' => 'Country',
        'records' => false
    );

    public $records = array(
        array('id' => '1','name' => 'Sweden', 'region_id' => '1'),
        array('id' => '2','name' => 'Norway', 'region_id' => '1')
    }
}
```

Now I'm thinking that I would like to test the data itself. For instance, I want to make sure that there are no countries that have lost their regions for some reason. Then I make a new Fixture which import all records.

```
class CountryLiveFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $import = array(
        'model' => 'Country',
        'records' => true
    );
}
```

Which works fine. But it seems unnecessary that I should have to create a second fixture. Is there any way I can set import records on the fly in a test?

Answer (score 1):

"am I getting the right number of records back from this method"

Advice:
You should be testing business logic, NOT what has already been TESTED by the framework.
If your query is correct, why would you need to test if you are indeed getting the right count? cake has already done that for you.

Comment: Well, yeah, but I'm not testing the framework, I'm testing the data. What I meant with my first example was that tests with fixed fixtures are good for testing methods like getCustomersThatFullFillRequirement, you can simply see that the no of records is correct, which you can't do with dynamic records.

The thing is, that we had an error that stemmed from some countries didn't have region_id (in this analogy). So we thought, why not write a test that looks at the data to see that we don't end up with the same kind of error again. Do you see what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: if your function only has query in it, you needn't test it really. you should pay more attention to your query maybe? if you added WHERE region_id IS NOT NULL to your query, you would always get the right result, except the fixture data changes.

Comment: The problem isn't the testing it self. The testing works as it is, like I stated. The problem is that I need to have two fixtures. One with static data, i e, where I set up att few posts manually, and one with dynamic data, i e, where I import all records from the database. My question is, is there any way that I can use only one Fixture and use the fixed data for some tests and the imported records for other tests.